# What is the best way to get a range of results?

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, int

I have a program that can be run from the command line with a `-R` to specify a range of results to return.  The `-R` takes one argument of the form `n:n`.

Seeing as though `n:n` could be 1-5 or 10000-500000, what is the best way of get the values on both sides of the `:`?

After passing my arg following `-R` to a method I started doing the following:

```
private int[] parseRangeResults(String range) {
   int[] rangeResults = new int[2];

   if(!(range.contains(":"))) {
      throw new Exception("Invalid range syntax");
   }

   String[] numbers = range.split(":")
   rangeResults[0] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
   rangeResults[1] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[2]);

   return rangeResults;
}
```

But I think this breaks down if someone puts special characters, or `1000:::::5000`, so what is the best way of handling this?

Comment: If the only problem is that it won't work if someone gives garbage input, I'm not sure that's a problem

Comment: @StephenTG I'm slow, care to elaborate?

Comment: Although now that I think about it, depending on the allowed range, negative values could be problematic

Comment: I think this best sums my original point up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out. On a slightly different note, do you need to account for negative numbers?

Comment: @StephenTG Thanks for the link!  Also, there should be no negative numbers

Comment: In that case what you have should work fine for any valid input. All you might want to do is put in a bit of error-trapping in case the user gives you something invalid. EDIT: My research shows that string.split will remove the "-", so you should be parsing numbers[0] and numbers[1]

Comment: Your name is so 2337... :D

Comment: @StephenTG I just thought of something... if I'm doing a split on `-` that will throw off my array results, right?

Comment: @AndreaLigios what does that mean? lol

Comment: Code for me = lol, that means :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios yea I know, I got bored lol.. I'm going to change it once I get my next 30 day name change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to check the input is with regular expressions if this `regex("\\d*-\\d*")` matches, then your output is correct. this is the code for your function

```
    String regex = "(\\d*):(\\d*)";
    Pattern checkInput = Pattern.compile(regex);

    Matcher matcherInput = checkInput.matcher(range);

    if(matcherInput.matches()){
        rangeResults[1] = Integer.parseInt(matcherInput.group(1));
        rangeResults[2] = Integer.parseInt(matcherInput.group(2));



    }
```

Comment: This is what I meant when I said error-trap for bad input. I lacked the regex expertise to actually come up with this magic

Comment: Or should I say regexpertise?

Comment: This doesn't work... I'm assuming it's because my function is passing a string and I'm trying to do a regex integer check against a string.

Comment: because you change the input, try to work with groups it will be easier. The regex that you have to use is (\d*):(\d*) and get the group 1 and 2.